# Can I re-factor Angular JS validation conditionals to streamline code?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

The below code is one row of my form.

I replicate "AddCarForm.uCarName.$dirty && AddCarForm.uCarName.$invalid" several times throughout the snippet. can i refactor this to a variable, that will be updated with the answer to the conditional as the user's input changes/ better way of refactoring?

```html
<div class="form-group required " ng-class="{'has-error': AddCarForm.uCarName.$dirty && AddCarForm.uCarName.$invalid}">
  <label class=" control-label col-lg-5 " for="uCarName">Name:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-7 ">
    <input type="text" ng-model="carDetails.carName" name="uCarName" class="form-control" required />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-show="AddCarForm.uCarName.$dirty && AddCarForm.uCarName.$invalid" class="error-msg col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-7">
      <span ng-show="AddCarForm.uCarName.$error.required"> Car Name required </span> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your controller, have that expression return from a function, i.e.:

```
$scope.shouldShow = function() {
      return $scope.AddCarForm.uCarName.$dirty && $scope.AddCarForm.uCarName.$invalid;
}
```

and then do:

```
ng-show="shouldShow();"
```

Just need to make sure the form is actually on the scope.

Comment: Makes sense thanks. Didn't occur to me I could access the the "AddCarform" variables from the controller